# Set the center of custom MKAnnotationView

Tags: swift3, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mapkitannotation

I am using the custom `MKAnnotationView`. I use the `autolayouts` which are working fine, but the position(frame) of annotation view is not appropriate.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
{
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation
    {
        return
    }

    let starbucksAnnotation = view.annotation as! LiquorLocation
    let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: nil, options: nil)
    let calloutView = views?[0] as! CustomCalloutView
    calloutView.labelLiquorShopName.text = starbucksAnnotation.title
    calloutView.labelLiquorShopAddress.text = starbucksAnnotation.address
    calloutView.labelLiquorShopAwayDistance.text = starbucksAnnotation.locationKmAway
    calloutView.imageViewLiquorShop.image = starbucksAnnotation.liquorShopIcon


    calloutView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(calloutView)
    mapView.setCenter((view.annotation?.coordinate)!, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

What I am doing wrong?  I want to center the annotation view at the top of the pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Autolayouts` again save my day. I add the layout constraint between my calloutview and view(MKAnnotationView). I write below lines underneath `view.addSubview(calloutView)` in `didSelect` method.

```
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: calloutView.frame.size.width)
        view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint])
```